# file access from javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, file

I'm trying to access a text file using javascript code, but I keep receiving a security error message. What I'm trying to do is:

```
var file = File('path/filename.txt');
```

The path is relative to the script location. I found that running from local machine could be the reason for that, so I tried to run from my local webserver but the error is still there. Does someone know why? What can I do to load this text file? If possible, considering that it is always under the script path, could it be also loaded from local disk (no web server)?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you get to the file from the browser?

Comment: yes, the file is accessible from the browser

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to access a file on the server, you should do it using a server side coding language like PhP.
If you're trying to access a client file (= a file on the computer of your website visitor), <strike>it's not possible for obvious security reasons</strike> [EDIT] Thanks to Colin DeClue , I discovered this is possible using the [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). An article explaining this is available here : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: `If you're trying to access a client file (= a file on the computer of your website visitor), it's not possible for obvious security reasons.`

Yes it is, in modern browsers. Read up on HTML5 File API.

Comment: Indeed, I had overlooked that possibility. I will update my answer accordingly. Thanks for pointing this out, I will remember it for sure !

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet will attempt to load the file from your local file system, so can't retrieve a file from a server. You'd need to look at `requestFileSystem` or `FileReader` to make something like this work if the file is local.

Alternatively, you could use AJAX to retrieve the file from a server.

Comment: How could I load it using FileReader? The file to load is chosen from user interaction: in this case I want to load a subtitle text file based on a video source.

Comment: You'll find [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and a [tutorial here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/#toc-file-readingbyname)

Comment: This answer seems like it could imply that you could use `requestFileSystem` or `FileReaser` to read files from the server. That's not the case. Those just make reading files from the user's local file system easier. If you need to read from the server, you need server side code.

Comment: @ColinDeClue Wording tweaked to clarify.